# Uploading base64_encoded image increasing file size from original size

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5, base64

I am using the below code to upload a base64 encoded image to s3.

```
$config = ['Expires' => '30 day','CacheControl' => 'max-age=31536000' ];
$path = 'website/'. $image;
Storage::getDriver()->put($path, base64_decode($b64str), $config);
```

after uploading, I notice that the file in s3 has a higher file size compared to the actual file size.

**is there any way I can upload with the same size?**

here I attached the file actual size and s3 size screenshot.

**Image 1 before the upload file size**

[image]

**Image 2 after the upload file size**

[image]

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are comparing the same file here

Comment: @RiggsFolly I doubled check many times after seeing a difference in file size.

Comment: You have to be doing something wrong somewhere, if you start with an image and convert it to Base64 and then back for an image the file size does not change by a single byte

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetly base64 **increases** file size.

> Each Base64 digit represents exactly 6 bits of data. So, three 8-bits bytes of the input string/binary file (3×8 bits = 24 bits) can be represented by four 6-bit Base64 digits (4×6 = 24 bits).
>
> This means that the Base64 version of a string or file will be at most
> 133% the size of its source (a ~33% increase). The increase may be
> larger if the encoded data is small. For example, the string "a" with
> length === 1 gets encoded to "YQ==" with length === 4 — a 300%
> increase.
>
> Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64

However, the size difference seems to be too big. Could you show how you encode images?

Comment: And if you notice, OP is doing a base64_DECODE() before storing, so one assumes they have encoded it somewhere else and this should be creating an image file again from the base64 version !! :)

Comment: If I understood you correctly then yes, he should show us how is he encoding images and not decoding.